# Undervolting XPS 13 9360

Tags: battery, script

I have just installed eOS on my Dell xps 9360 and I'm hoping to get a bit more juice out of the aging battery. I see people on win10 undervolting the CPU/GPU to get more battery life and I bumped into this Bash script;

https://gist.github.com/Mnkai/6a949aff19c0744e30b0f7c324c1fe9d

Which seems to be specifically for i7-8550U (I have i5-7200U)

So my questions are;

Should I undervolt?
Would this script work?
If it would,how would I use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use https://github.com/georgewhewell/undervolt on my XPS 9560 and works very nicely.  I've created the services and triggers myself as per the guides on that GitHub site and I'm happy with the results of lowering the overall noise and temps a bit.

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a go.